# How to mount tmp folder as it originally mounted on Ubuntu 18

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I was updating the OS and received an error message:

```
mount: /tmp: mount point not mounted or bad option.
```

So I read through this site and did some testing for the mount point:

```
[03:02:10] root@deecee / # systemctl status tmp.mount
Unit tmp.mount could not be found.
```

The fstab doesn't contain anything about a /tmp folder being mounted at boot so I tried to enable the tmp.mount

```
[03:08:32] root@deecee / # systemctl enable tmp.mount
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/tmp.mount → /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount.

[03:08:41] root@deecee / # systemctl status tmp.mount
● tmp.mount - Temporary Directory (/tmp)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
    Where: /tmp
     What: tmpfs
     Docs: man:hier(7)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
```

How should I proceed to mount the tmp folder as it originally came in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: /tmp is normally a part of the root filesystem, no mount.  Of course, you can explicitly make a mount there, but that was never a default for a release.

Comment: @ubfan I forced an umount and tried to update the OS but I still get the same message: ```mount: /tmp: mount point not mounted or bad option.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shut down the small service I was running on the machine. I forced the /tmp folder to umount and then mounted the folder.

```
[04:52:11] root@deecee / # umount -f -l /tmp

[04:54:49] root@deecee / # mount tmpfs /tmp -t tmpfs -o mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev

[04:55:04] root@deecee / # systemctl status tmp.mount
● tmp.mount - Temporary Directory (/tmp)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (mounted) since Mon 2022-08-22 16:55:04 EDT; 4s ago
    Where: /tmp
     What: tmpfs
     Docs: man:hier(7)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
```

With that being done, I could update the OS without any errors.